# Hakko FX-888D Iron Issue

Tags: soldering, flux, soldering-iron-station

I just got a new Hakko 888D for Christmas.  I have used it a bit since then, and I'm using the wet sponge, brass sponge, and some RadioShack tip cleaner to maintain the tip quality.  The issue I am having is simple, and I might know the source but I lack a fix.  The very tip of the tip, when new, looks like the first picture with the bag.  It has a different color, and presumably a different metal, at the end.  That part gets very hot, but the shinier parts don't, and solder will NOT adhere to them.  This is likely intentional by Hakko and I like this.  My issue, as shown in picture #2, is that the shiny part is getting oxidized.  It may be ineffectual due to the fact that the oxidized portion doesn't get solder on it anyway, but it's spreading.  It's now on the non-replaceable part of the iron in small quantities.  I can't remove it with any of my aforementioned cleaning "tools".  It could be oxidizing due to the flux in my lead free solder, but it uses resin which isn't corrosive like rosin.

**My question: why is this happening and how can I fix it?  I've had this for 2 days "

[image: new tip]

[image: oxidization]

[image: yay a new station]

Comment: At what temp do you solder, and how do you set it when first powering up the unit?

Comment: A bit of discoloration is normal, but if the tip getting pitted or eroded then you may have a fake https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvOJL8aAUO8

Comment: I have it set at 650 usually.  When I turn it on, I wood it on the brass sponge, tin it completely, wipe it, and lightly tin it again

Comment: Confirmed I have a legit one with that video

Comment: just checking the obvious: do you set your temp via the ENTER key or via the UP key? (Or, to make it short: are you aware of the UI trap that might bring a "I don't read manuals" user to miscalibrate the tool?). And BTW, I take the unit is set for Fahrenheit, correct? :-)

Comment: It's set for Fahrenheit, yes.  I set it by holding a button, pressing up and enter to set it to 650 number by number.  Every time I turn it on, it shows 650 for a second and then climbs to match 650.

Comment: If you're finding a problem transferring enough heat from the supplied conical tip, a [T18-D24](http://www.hakko.com/english/tip_selection/series_t18.html#type_d) tip might be better and allow you to use a lower temperature.

Comment: Mine didn't come with a conical tip  it came with the D16, which I'm happy about!  Although, a conical tip is somewhat useful on occasion.

Comment: @Bobdabiulder A D16 sounds more useful than the conical tip I got with a UK-region one. If you don't *need* to use lead-free solder, the normal stuff is easier to work with, in my limited experience. After my Multicore (TM) brand solder ran out, I got some HQ brand solder, which seems to work really well - you might find some other make works well for you. Great Xmas present!

Comment: I agree, it was a great present 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very tip of the soldering bit is plated and accepts molten solder, the rest of the bit tends to repel it. The part that matters most is the shiny tip which is best cleaned with brass wire wool (which is a soft metal) or Multicore TTC followed by wiping with a damp **cellulose** sponge. It's very common for flux and contamination to gradually build up on the non-plated part of the bit. These can be kept to a minimum by wiping as above but they are unlikely to be removed altogether. I have some pics on my old [basic soldering guide](http://www.epemag.wimborne.co.uk/solderpix.htm) showing just the same thing happening on my old Ungar iron. 20 years on it's still going strong.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is normal as long as you take good care of the very tip as this is whats used for the soldering. The rest will get oxidized and its normal

Comment: How long have you been soldering?  Have you experienced this??

Comment: @Bobdabiulder For a while